# 'Attempt to de-reference a null object' with Field__c.contains()

Tags: apex, error, if, contains

When I use `contains`, I get `Attempt to de-reference a null object`:

```
for(Gear__c g : gears{
   if(toolsMap.get(g.Id).Status__c == 'Off' || toolsMap.get(g.Id).HelpText__c.contains('Hello there!')){
        System.debug('Here we go');
   }
}
```

When I change `contains` to `==`, everything is fine. But I can have a few values in this field. How to write `if` logic to avoid the error?

Comment: You need to add a null check before accessing any field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that `toolsMap.get(g.Id).HelpText__c` always returns a value. This may not be true. So whenever it returns `null`, your current code will fail as you observe.

A refactored version of your code should look as below:

```
if(toolsMap.get(g.Id).Status__c == 'Off' 
     || (
            toolsMap.get(g.Id).HelpText__c != null 
                 && toolsMap.get(g.Id).HelpText__c.contains('Hello there!')
        ) {
    ...
}
```